# "Unknown theoremstyle" warning with Springer Nature template

Tags: theorems, document-classes, amsthm, springernature

As displayed in the table below, the Springer Nature journal article template (available through Overleaf [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/myxmhdsbzkyd) or from the Springer Nature website [here](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support/see-where-our-services-will-take-you/18782940)) is supposed to have three predefined theorem styles:  [image: table of predefined theorem styles]

In the supplied `sn-jnl.cls` file, these environments are presumably defined by the following code:

```
\newtheoremstyle{thmstyleone}% Numbered
{18pt plus2pt minus1pt}% Space above
{18pt plus2pt minus1pt}% Space below
{\small\itshape}% Body font
{0pt}% Indent amount
{\small\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem headi
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
\thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
%
 \newtheoremstyle{thmstyletwo}% Numbered
{18pt plus2pt minus1pt}% Space above
{18pt plus2pt minus1pt}% Space below
{\small\normalfont}% Body font
{0pt}% Indent amount
{\small\itshape}% Theorem head font
 {}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem headi
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
%
\newtheoremstyle{thmstylethree}% Definition
{18pt plus2pt minus1pt}% Space above
{18pt plus2pt minus1pt}% Space below
{\small\normalfont}% Body font
{0pt}% Indent amount
{\small\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem headi
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
```

The code for the head/body text formatting in the second style seems to be flipped from what is claimed in the table above; however, I'm running into a much more basic problem.  In their sample `sn-article.tex` document, they assign the following styles:

```
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
%%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]% meant for sectionwise numbers
%% optional argument [theorem] produces theorem numbering sequence instead of independent numbers for Proposition
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%%\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}% to get separate numbers for theorem and proposition etc.

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
```

However, when I compile the `sn-article.tex` document on Overleaf or my local machine, I receive the following warnings:
[image: unknown theoremstyle warning]

Moreover, all of the environments in the compiled PDF look indistinguishable to me:
[image: theorem, proposition, example, and remark environments]
[image: definition environment]

Question: Why are the theorem styles not behaving as claimed/expected and can this be fixed by modifying the `sn-article.tex` file (but without modifying the `sn-jnl.cls` file)?

Comment: The main issue having been solved, the two theoremstyles are still messed up, arent' they?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The template is set up with this preamble outline in `sn-article.tex`:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference 
% <some more package loading>
\usepackage{amsthm}%
% <some more preamble stuff>
```

So, one would think that [`amsthm`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)-related structures (like the theorem styles) would be loaded properly. However, the definition of these styles happen *within* `sn-jnl.cls`. So, at the time that class file is processed, `amsthm` has not been loaded, and therefore the theorem definitions aren't executed. Within `sn-jnl.cls` it checks whether `amsmath` is loaded before defining the styles, but again, at the time the class file is processed, no `amsthm` is present, so it just ignores anything `amsthm`-related.

The template (`sn-article.tex`) should have been set up in this way:

```
\RequirePackage{amsthm}

\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference 
% <some more package/preamble stuff>
```

With the above order, `amsthm` is loaded before the class, thereby defining the appropriate theorem styles.

Comment: It's unbelievable that Springer Nature made such a dumb mistake and that they still haven't fixed it.

Comment: @tparker: indeed, you'd expect to have the money to get their act straight. That tells you how the company is actually run...